# PySQLPool getting old data until restart

Tags: python

I am facing a problem where data from MySQL retrieved using PySQLPool is returned as the db was at start of process, INSERT or UPDATE queries from python or MySQL client do not show up until a kill and re-run of the python process.

Would appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: for reference, this solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318347/why-are-some-mysql-connections-selecting-old-data-the-mysql-database-after-a-del

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: [Why are some mysql connections selecting old data the mysql database after a delete + insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318347/why-are-some-mysql-connections-selecting-old-data-the-mysql-database-after-a-del)

MySQL's isolation level was causing this. Somehow only python clients get affected and never stumbled across this issue earlier. It is a valid problem and has a detailed solution. My question was targeting python and pySQLPool because it did not occur to me that MySQL could be the one causing this. Now my deployment procedure includes details on altering global isolation level for MySQL to be "READ-COMMITTED".

SET GLOBAL tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';