# Simultaneous MySQLdb connections not seeing updates

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm creating a few different scripts that all interact with a central MySQL database to share data but I'm finding that some changes I make to the database wont propagate through or be readable to certain scripts until the database connection has been closed and re opened.

For example using the following code `read_script` will only print items that have been added to the database using `write_script`after I quit and restart `write_script`. I'm new to MySQL so I'm not sure if there is a problem in my SQL or my python

## read_script

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(...)
while True:
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")
    print cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
```

## write_script

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(...)
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(some_data)")
cur.close()
connection.commit()
```

What do I need to do to ensure I get up to data data from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default transaction isolation is REPEATABLE READ. This means that your read_script will always read and show the same data. Put commit in your while-loop. Side note: Probably good to temporise reading using `time.sleep(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like the assumption is that you are only going to perform a single transaction and then disconnect. If you have a different need, then you need to work around this assumption. You can put in a commit (though I would use a rollback if you are not actually changing data). Or you can change the isolation level on the cursor as mentioned by @geertjanvdk - from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677379/how-do-you-change-the-sql-isolation-level-from-python-using-mysqldb) I used this:

`dbcursor.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED")`

Or, it looks like you can set auto commit to true on the connection:

`dbconn.autocommit(True)`

Though, again, this is not recommended if actually making changes in the connection.