# How to refresh MySQL data in Treeview Tkinter?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

**Code**

I have this function:

```
#Refresh MySQL data to Treeview
    def refresh(self):
        self.table.delete(*self.table.get_children())

        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select * from requested order by done")
        for row in cursor:
            self.table.insert('','end', values = (row[8], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[9], row[10], row[12]))
```

If I insert a record or update one - using workbench. When I press refresh in Tkinter, it does not show any new or amended data. Just stays as it is.

But - If I quit Tkinter app - re-open it - click `refresh` it will show new amended data.

If the tkinter app is running - If I try to run the following query: `truncate table` using workbench - MySQL will not complete the query the action until I close the tkinter app

**What it should do**

When I activate the function `refresh` - it should remove all the current data in treeview and update it with existing values within MySQL.

**Quesiton**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you verfied your `.execute(...` yields new or even any data?

Comment: @stovfl not sure what you mean. But here is an additional information - If the tkinter app is running - If I try to  `truncate` from workbench - it will not do anything until I close the tkinter app

Comment: First step, add `print('in refresh')` inside `def refresh(...)` to verify it get called at ***"I press refresh"***.

Comment: @stovfl yes, it is printing every-time I click the button - do you need the full code?

Comment: This ***"it is printing every-time I click the button"*** is contradict to ***"it will not do anything until I close the tkinter app"***. Second step, add `print('row[8]')` inside `for row in ...` to verify you get what you think from `mysql`

Comment: @stovfl My bad wording - What I meant was... ***If I try to run the following query: truncate table using workbench - MySQL will not complete the query the action until I close the tkinter app***

Comment: Got it, sounds like a concurent access locking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204071/discussion-between-stovfl-and-lv98).

Comment: You probably have an issue with [MySQL transaction isolation level](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-transaction/#isolation-levels)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Hi, that really helped me thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  [@brunodesthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) link in comments  [MySQL transaction isolation level](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-transaction/#isolation-levels) has helped me find what was wrong!

By running this query in MySQL Workbench:

```
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

Has allowed me to update records from MySQL and run this function below - without a problem!

```
#Refresh MySQL data to Treeview
    def refresh(self):
        self.table.delete(*self.table.get_children())

        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select * from requested order by done")
        for row in cursor:
            self.table.insert('','end', values = (row[8], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[9], row[10], row[12]))
```

Comment: You probably want to set the transaction isolation level in your own code (cf [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677379/how-do-you-change-the-sql-isolation-level-from-python-using-mysqldb)) when opening the db connection, so you're sure you always get it right.

Comment: That would make sense!